# Always get AlreadySubmittedException after form is submitted in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm new to Symfony so I need little help.

I have this code

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //TODO
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('news'));
    }
```

When the form is submitted, I always obtain 500 Internal Server Error - AlreadySubmittedException.

Comment: Is this the full code of your controller?

Comment: No it isn't. It is part of the indexAction method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use $form->handleRequest OR $form->submit, not both.

Comment: How did I miss that :)